# Line wrapping TeX from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I'm seeking a command that when I highlight a paragraph of text in Visual Studio Code will let me remove all line breaks, and correspondingly a command that if I highlight a paragraph without line breaks will insert them at the end of the display width.

It wont be enough to just use `Alt-Z` because that just makes the display show the line wrapping but doesn't actually insert the line breaks.

For context: I'm using a VS Code latex plugin which is a compiled text editor format.  Errors in this system trace back to line numbers so if you don't have line breaks you have to hunt down the error somewhere in a large paragraph.  But of course this being a text document there you often have to edit paragraphs and end-of-lines become jagged and hard to read/update.

Answer (score 8):

You can set this behavior searching for "Word Wrap" in the settings. Set to "on" to wrap the words.

Comment: Thanks.  This approach by the way is the same as `Alt-Z` which as I mentioned does not solve the problem for latex which needs hard line breaks to track errors.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution, maybe it will help someone in the future.: install "rewrap" extension.  Select portion of text, and use `Alt-q`.  Seems to work like Emacs' `M-q` command. (Thx Grant)

Comment: Minor: rewarp should be rewrap